# Applying foreground color / highlight to specific rows of the excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, automation, apache-poi

Am copying data/ sheet from one excel workbook to another workbook using copyRow. I want to apply foreground color to specific rows in my target excel. Below is the code i have now. Please help how should i do it. 
Found the link for Cell Style from POI's quick guide. But please help to use it to apply it to specific rows in the target excel.

```
https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills
```

**My Program**

public class Color1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Color1.xlsx"));
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    copyRow(workbook, sheet, 0 , 1);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Color2.xlsx");
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
}

private static void copyRow(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet worksheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
    // Getting the source / new row
    XSSFRow newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);       
    XSSFRow sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

    // Looping through source columns to add to new row
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        // Grab a copy of the old/new cell

        XSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
        XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: There's comment in the example by FillsAndFrills reference
```
// Orange "foreground", foreground being the fill foreground not the font color.
```

It sounds ambiguous, but probably you want to change a font color?

Comment: i dont want to change the font color. Any color is fine, just want to apply it to specific row in my destination / target excel sheet.